# How to make the toggle button for Drawer/Sidebar appear above the main content and appbar?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Solution for main issue: As vatsal said, the toggle button should be moved above the drawer, then we take the advantage of the open state of the drawer and change the left property of the button in the toggleButton class: `left: props => (props.open ?` ${drawerWidth - 30}px `: '30px')`

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-4neblr

Edit 2: Also, how can I prevent the drawer from pushing the appbar and main content?
I want the open state of the drawer to appear above them.

Edit 1: Here's a demo from material ui v4 page, with the issue I'm currently facing:

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-j9e96u

Hello

I'm using Material UI v4 and the drawer mini variant component,I have been trying to get the toggle button as the image below for two days without success:

[image]

Here's what I get:

[image]

Position absolute is not working, and when I add overflow:visible on the paper component that the drawer is using it, I get the first look but with an issue, where the links/buttons on the sidebar overflow:

[image]

It's driving me crazy, any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved

```
<IconButton className={classes.toggleButton} onClick={handleDrawerToggle}>
        {open ? <ChevronLeftIcon /> : <ChevronRightIcon />}
      </IconButton>
```

above drawer now you can add the conditional styles I have made the comment in `toggleButton`
[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-0r67w9?file=/demo.js)

Comment: And by taking advantage of the open state of the drawer I can change the left property of the button in the toggleButton class :

left: props => (props.open ? `${drawerWidth - 30}px` : '30px'),

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to make the drawer appear above the main content, when it's open?
currently it's pushing the main content.

Comment: Check the code sandbox I have made changes in `drawer` styles zIndex and marginTop

Comment: I meant the drawer/sidebar to be above the rest of the page like modal, like in stackoverflow.com or v4.mui.com

Comment: added `position:'absolute'` in the drawer now I think that's what you wanted

Comment: Exactly, And now because the drawer went out of the document flow, I just pushed the root container of appbar and main content to the right using margin left.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-myku5k

Thanks a lot!